# Entity Framework 6 map shadow property on read

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

Is it possible to put value from shadow property during read from DB to any not mapped column in my Entity model?

Main reason for that is that I would like to get from database values for columns: PeriodStart, PeriodEnd for Teporal (System Versioned) table.

Problem is described here but actually nothing worked for me for EF 6:
https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/26463

Comment: I do not understand something. Shadow properties is only EF Core feature, isn't?

Comment: Shadow properties are supported in EF6, though to my knowledge temporal table mapping via mechanisms like `AsOf()` is not. Is this an EF Core 6 question?